# How to notify Clients if ActiveMQ broker is down?

Tags: java, jms, activemq-classic, middleware

I want clients to get notification whenever my activemq broker is down for any reason.

How can this be done? Is there any callback mechanism?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the broker is down, your clients will lose connection.  If you are using the failover uri, then you may not be aware this is occurring without a TransportListener. If not, you really want your clients to know, then you can handle your own reconnect logic and when the client loses connection, or gets any other connectivity error (ie connection refused) you can list the broker being down as a possibility.

Otherwise you would need to have some other monitoring service dedicated to monitoring the broker(s) health and the clients could check that if the fact that the cannot connect is not enough reason to indicate that there is something wrong.

Comment: does org.apache.activemq.transport.TransportListener helps in this in any way? (I am using failover uri (master-slave))

Comment: Yes, it can give you insight into when some connectivity issue occurs when using the failover uri, but not limited to a broker being down.  I've updated the response to reflect this. Why do you want your clients to know this?  What are you trying to solve?  Logging and/or statistics?

Comment: I have system with activemq broker and two other parts, so if system is down it can be because of any of the three parts, I want to know if it is broker which is down or other parts, So if client can know broker is down so I know that its broker because of which complete system is down.

Comment: TransportListener (or the other method i mentioned) should be fine as long as you understand that fail overs result from network outages as well and does not necessarily mean the broker is down.

Comment: I just want that client get to know there is something wrong with broker connection, As I am using failover uri, So client reconnect to failover broker if primary broker goes down and vice versa but I still want my clients to know that primary and/or failover is down. One way is to use TransportListener, are there other effective ways?

Comment: Other than what I already mentioned (handling your own reconnect logic) no.  One of the main purposes of the TransportListener is to give you some insight into what is going on with connection state in a failover URI.  Otherwise failover assumes you don't really care why, just as long as you reconnect.

Comment: thanks Erik, I am not worried about reconnect logic that will be taken care by failover, all I want is to explore what all are possibility for a client to know that there is something wrong with connection and use which is best among them. By now all I found is TransportListener interface and exceptionListener. But found somewhere exceptionListener is not good in failover uri.

Comment: can you please tell what is purpose of onCommand method in transportListener?